# Only allow load() to fire one time on scroll

Tags: jquery

I know there are only about a bazillion posts here on SO for how to use `.one` but I am just not skilled enough in jquery to grasp what I am trying to do, which I am sure I am complicating far beyond what I should be.

I am using the [OnScreen](http://benpickles.github.io/onScreen) jQuery plugin to check if a specific `div` is visible on the screen.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($("#showBlogs").is(':onScreen')) {
        $("#showMoreBlogs").show().load("path/to/file.php");
    }
});
```

and my html code is such:

```
<div id="showBlogs" style="display:none"></div>
```

This does work, but every time the page scrolls down via mouse or down arrow key, the `load()` fires off again, when the div is within view of course, but obviously having it reload every time is not good.

Now I know that the [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function exists, but I am just not figuring out bring these two things together.

How do I get this `scroll` with `is(':onScreen')` to work with `.one(function)`?? That is what has me stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have set up ... it would be easier just to add a couple of lines:

```
$(document).scroll(function(event) {
    if($("#showBlogs").is(':onScreen')) {
        $("#showMoreBlogs").show().load("path/to/file.php");
        $(this).off(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: The jQuery api says that 
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
});
is equivalent to
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
  $( this ).off( event );
});
Hence the OPs suggestion to use .one is correct and you are adding unnecessary lines.

Comment: This method does appear to load the file on initial scroll into view and not have it reloaded on any additional scrolling.

Comment: You don't really need a `self` variable, because `this` will work within the if statement, but otherwise unbinding the handler is the way to go. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`$(document).one("scroll", function() {
    if($("#showBlogs").is(':onScreen')) {
        $("#showMoreBlogs").load("path/to/file.php");
    }
} );`

Let me know if it worked. :-)

Comment: This did work in loading the file, but it kept firing on every scroll.

Comment: Try the edited version. There was a typo. This function will only fire once, when the page is scrolled. Never after.

Comment: Well then I don't know why it should fire on every scroll. $(document).one("scroll", function() {
    alert('hi');
} ); fires only once for me.

Comment: Using `.one()` for this purpose will only work if the first scroll event happens to put that particular div into view - you can't count on that.

Comment: @nnnnnn -- so, what you are getting at here, let me just make sure I understand what you are saying, is that the first time I scrolled my mouse, it fired off the `.is` check, but every mouse scroll after that it did *not* do a check because the `.one` had already done its 'once' and that is all she wrote. Basically got that right?

Comment: @Abela - Yes. So if the first scroll didn't scroll far enough the `.load` will never happen.